# Why won't a position:absolute div show up? Even though it's in a position relative div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0jrzz1gw/

**Why won't the output show `This is A4`?**

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#a1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a3 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
}
#a4 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">This is Div 1
    <div id="a1">This is A1</div>
    <div id="a2">This is A2</div>
    <div id="a3">
        <div id="a4">This is A4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then, similarly as strange, why won't the code show 
`This is A3` after this simple modification:
http://jsfiddle.net/0jrzz1gw/1/

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#a1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a3 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
}
#a4 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">This is Div 1
    <div id="a1">This is A1</div>
    <div id="a2">This is A2</div>
    <div id="a3">
        This is A3
        <div id="a4">This is A4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

You've set the top, left, right and bottom to 0, which means the element has a 0 x 0px size.

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#a1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a3 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
}
#a4 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">This is Div 1
    <div id="a1">This is A1</div>
    <div id="a2">This is A2</div>
    <div id="a3">
        This is A3
        <div id="a4">This is A4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a general suspicion that you be confused about the definition of relative absolute positioning. Unlike relative position, absolutely positioned elements are **taken out of the document flow** and does not contribute towards the calculation of the parent's dimensions.

With regards to your first question, the reason is simply because when you absolutely position an element, it is removed from the document flow (see explanation above). Since `#a3` is the **only child** of the parent, the parent's dimensions will collapse to zero and so will the child.

To remedy this, specify a height:

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#a1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a3 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 100px;
}
#a4 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">This is Div 1
    <div id="a1">This is A1</div>
    <div id="a2">This is A2</div>
    <div id="a3">
        <div id="a4">This is A4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

With regards to your second question, there is a text node in `#a3` and therefore the element will not collapse. However, since you have set the child `#a4` to be absolutely positioned with the four coordinates (top, left, bottom, right) all set to zero, you are effectively forcing the absolutely positioned child to **cover the parent entirely**, therefore obscuring all content underneath. You can see that if I forcibly stretch the parent to 100px, `#a4` will also cover all 100px.

```css
#a {
    position: relative;
    background-color: green;
}
#a1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a2 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: blue;
}
#a3 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: beige;
    height: 100px;
}
#a4 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">This is Div 1
    <div id="a1">This is A1</div>
    <div id="a2">This is A2</div>
    <div id="a3">
        This is A3
        <div id="a4">This is A4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```